# python "com.chaquo.python.PyException: ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused "

Tags: python, android-studio, sockets, chaquopy

Im using Chaquopy lib and I'm trying to connect my python node to my server.
The node code is inside my android app but the server code is not.

The server code:

```
class Block_Net:
   BlockChaine=[]
   nodes=[]
   PORT = 8000
   FORMAT = "utf-8"
   HEADER = 1024
   ADR = ("127.0.0.1", PORT)
   server=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
   server.bind(ADR)
   def __init__(self):
       print("\n Sever is Starting... \n")
       time.sleep(1)
       self.server.listen()
       print("|||- Server is listing on PORT: "+str(self.PORT)+" -|||\n")
       while True:
           connection, ADR = self.server.accept()  
           connection.send(bytes("|||- you are connected -|||\n", self.FORMAT))
           print("|||- New node :  "+"**** "+str(ADR)+" ****"+" is connected -|||\n")
           self.nodes.append(connection.recv(self.HEADER).decode(self.FORMAT))
```

The node code:

```
def start(firstName,secondeName,cardeNum):
   PORT = 8000
   FORMAT = "utf-8"
   HEADER = 1024
   ADR = ("127.0.0.1", PORT)
   node=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
   with open(join(dirname(__file__),"condidats.json"),'r') as file:
       condidats=json.load(file)
       print(condidats)
       file.close()
   print("\n ------------------ "+str(firstName)+" -------- "+str(secondeName)+" -------- "+str(cardeNum)+" ------------------ \n")
   node.connect(ADR)
   thread=threading.Thread(target=host,args=[node,FORMAT])
   thread.start()
   return str(condidats)       
def host(node,FORMAT):
   PORT2=random.randint(2000,8080)
   sock=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
   sock.bind((socket.gethostname(),PORT2))
   node.send(bytes(str(sock.getsockname()),FORMAT))
```

Comment: *"The node code is inside my android app but the server code is not."* - in this case you cannot use `127.0.0.1` as address. `127.0.0.1` refers to the loopback adapter on the local machine, i.e. it is only reachable from applications on the same machine itself. The server might listen on `0.0.0.0` (all interfaces) and the client must specify the IP address of the server or a hostname which will be resolved to the IP address.

Comment: I changed it to my pc IP addresse but still not working

Comment: Please reflect **exactly** what you did and **exactly** what error message you get by editing your question. It might just be that you did it wrong.

Comment: If you're running your app on an emulator, have a look at the [emulator networking documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking). In particular, you could try making your app access your PC using the 10.0.2.2 address.

Comment: Thank you, I solved the problem this morning. As you said I changed the server addresses to ***127.0.0.1*** and the node address to ***10.0.2.2*** and it's working.